# Define key for disabled select box in django

Tags: django, forms

I have a form that has disabled select box. I have this function in UpdateForm():

```
def clean_job(self):
    f = self.fields['job'].widget.attrs
    if f.has_key('disabled') and f['disabled'] == 'disabled' :
        return self.instance.job
    else:
        return self.cleaned_data['job']
```

But when submitting the form I have this error : `Key 'job' not found in <QueryDict:`
How can I assign a key for a disabled selectbox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Disabled fields are not posted to the server](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1). The error isn't shown here, but somewhere you're accessing `request.POST['job']` - it would be helpful to post the full traceback.

Comment: I know that disabled fields are not posted to the server but I have to send a value to server and I have to define a key for disabled selectbox (user couldnot edit the job and job value must be an old job)

Comment: So include the job ID as a hidden field, and don't use a disabled select to display it - just render the value in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *have* to send send something for `job` to the server. What you *have* to do is properly handle exceptions in your code. Accessing a key directly in a dictionary will result in an error if that key doesn't exist, so you simply don't do that. Instead, use the `get` method on the dict, or `QueryDict` in this case.

```
job = request.POST.get('job') # stores `None` if doesn't exist
if job is not None:
    # do something
```

Or you can provide a default value:

```
job = request.POST.get('job', 'default job')
```